# How Python interact with JVM inside Spark

Tags: jvm, apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing Python code to develop some Spark applications. I am really curious how Python interact with running JVM and started reading the source code of Spark.

I can see that in the end, all the Spark transformations/actions ended up be calling certain jvm methods in the following way.

```
self._jvm.java.util.ArrayList(),
self._jvm.PythonAccumulatorParam(host, port))
self._jvm.org.apache.spark.util.Utils.getLocalDir(self._jsc.sc().conf())
self._jvm.org.apache.spark.util.Utils.createTempDir(local_dir, "pyspark") \
            .getAbsolutePath()
...
```

As a Python programmer, I am really curious what is going on with this `_jvm` object. However, I have briefly read all the source code under [pyspark](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/python/pyspark) and only found `_jvm` to be an attribute of [Context](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/context.py) class, beyond that, I know nothing about neither `_jvm's` attributes nor methods.

Can anyone help me understand how pyspark translate into JVM operations? should I read some scala code and see if `_jvm` is defined there?

Comment: It uses [py4j](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/). There is a special protocol to translate python calls into JVM calls. All of this you can find in Pyspark code, see [java_gateway.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py)

Comment: I've also found this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/PySpark+Internals) helpful:

Comment: @artemdevel it would be nice to convert that comment into an answer. Perhaps there's not much one can add to it.

Comment: @artemdevel you should convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: @Chris here you are :)

Answer (score 3):

It uses [py4j](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/). There is a special protocol to translate python calls into JVM calls. All of this you can find in Pyspark code, see [java_gateway.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py)